# What is the difference between a physical width and CSS width in pixels?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, pixel

I am currently using Photoshop, to create a series of Wireframes, for a future website design.  Naturally, I will be wanting the website to be responsive; which will be aided by Bootstrap.

I will be working with the Smartphone screen sizes first and then scaling up the screen sizes accordingly.

According to Bootstrap, Smartphones generally range between 480px to 767px.  Admittedly, the later being more Tablet based.

Where I am a little uncertain, is that when I check out the phone specifications, the physical screen widths are much greater than the CSS widths.

Let's take the HTC One phone.  The CSS screen dimensions are 360px by 640px whilst the physical screen width is 1080px by 1920px.  Referring to the width, this would suggest the physical screen width is 3 times width than the CSS width of the website.  After looking at a few websites, on the HTC One, the websites' widths are certainly not 3 times smaller than the actually screen's physical width.

I am just wondering if I have misunderstood something here.  For example, pixels may be a different size when measuring physical screens for example.

Comment: Be aware of the various units of measurement you can use in CSS - you may want to use something other than `px` [css units](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/length) - I've seen many sites now using `rem` for scalable units. You have things like `vh` which is _"Equal to 1% of the height of the viewport's initial containing block."_

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have not heard of `rem`.  Is this a variation of `em`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS width is what's used by the browser/css.

Physical width tells you how many pixels the physical screens pack into every css pixel i.e. modern high-density screens can have 2x or 3x more pixels packed into every css pixel. Keyword "retina" screen.

If you divide 1080px (physical) by 360px (css), you'll get 3. That means this screen has 3x the pixel density as compared to a normal, old-school screen.

Consequence: An image for that device needs to be 3x larger than normal css size in order to appear sharp (and not fuzzy) on that device.

So, for the sake of Photoshop wireframing you want to use css width only. But when creating the actual images later you might want them to have in 3 different sizes:

1) Normal (the same as css width)

2) 2x bigger for screens with 2x pixel density

3) 3x bigger for screens with 3x pixel density.

EDIT:

Here's an amazing piece of a slow-mo video showing exactly what's going on on a high-density screen. Watch how each individual pixel consists not only of 3 different color pixels but also how each color pixel consists of multiple physical pixels: https://youtu.be/3BJU2drrtCM?t=7m30s

Comment: Thank you for this insight.  Are you saying that a phone with a pixel density of 3, for example, is basically saying that they fit in 3 CSS pixels per 'phone' pixel; thus offering the opportunity to display a sharper image?

Comment: More or less. What normally would have been just one pixel is the combination of 3 physical pixels of the phone. So, the phone packs more pixels into every css pixel thus making things appear much sharper than normal because the resolution is higher that way.

Comment: The phone is basically trying to do the same thing as when you increase the resolution of an image from 100 dpi to 300 dpi. The principle is the same. Higher resolution = sharper image.

Comment: Gotcha!  Thank you.  I was initially under the impression the physical pixel dimension, was referring to the actual screen size.

Comment: Here's an amazing piece of a slow-mo video showing exactly what's going on on a high-density screen. Watch how each individual css pixel consists not only of 3 different color pixels but also how each color pixel consists of multiple physical pixels: https://youtu.be/3BJU2drrtCM?t=7m30s

Comment: Great link.  Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment when devices with very high pixel density were issued, all software/sites on the market would be rendered too small and unreadable, so nobody would buy those devices. Vendors introduced logical pixels, so that existing sites would be rendered as usual, but fonts and vector icons would look smoother as there is extra sharpness due to physical pixels being smaller than logical.